# C# "Like" search similiar to SQL Query "LIKE"

Tags: c#

Here's my scenario. I'm doing a phone number registration component which will reject some numbers with particular prefixes (Eg. "95973" or "95949"). I've stored these prefixes in the database already.

What I'd like to know is, is there any C# method which I can use to match the registration number with the prefixes I'd like to reject.

**UPDATED WITH PSEUDO CODE**

```
BEGIN
GET phone num FROM querystring
FOR EACH banned prefix IN DB
    CHECK if phone num BEGINS WITH banned prefix
        IF TRUE, RESPOND TO phone num WITH error message
        ELSE, REGISTER phone num
END EACH
END
```

Comment: You can use Regex. Linq. substrings checks can you give a little more info on how you have the phone numbers and the prefixes represented in your code.

Comment: Do you just want to do SomeString.Contains("95973")?

Answer (score 5):

You may use [String.StartWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452.aspx) method.

```
 string phone = "9182323243";
 string[] prefix = {"93","94","85"};

 if (prefix.Any(pre => phone.StartsWith(pre)))
     //Reject
 else
     //Accept
```

Answer (score 2):

Most simple:

```
        var prefix = "95973";
        var number = "95973-123456";
        var reject = number.Contains(prefix);
        var reject2 = number.StartsWith(prefix);
```

Answer (score 2):

The quick and unefficient way, that describes what you are doing, is the following LINQ line:

```
// load all prefixes
IEnumerable<string> prefixes = GetPrefixes();

// does Any prefix exists such that "number" starts with it?
bool reject = prefixes.Any(p => number.StartsWith(p))
```

If you know that your prefix is always long 5 you can do with a very efficient exact lookup:

```
string number = "1234567889";

// get the prefix part
string prefix = number.Substring(0, 5);

// check if prefixes contains it
bool reject = prefixes.Contains(prefix);
```

In any case, if you don't update prefixes too often and they are not a huge amount (if they are long 5 chars they are not a huge amount:)) I suggest you to load them from the DB in memory, say in a `HashSet<string>` and use the latter approach, it's going to be bleezing fast.

Answer (score 0):

I already have experience writting OS for PBX. So, the best way in your situation is writting *rules* like this:
* - any numer of digits, may be 0
? - one any digit

Example:

rule: "23948??", Number should starts from "23948" and should contains 2 digits after

rule: "9*", all numbers, starts from digit 9 (in this case PBX must to wait user input for example 2 seconds after each entered digit and before next one).

So, in this case you must to use Regex